# How to update GeoWebCache as part of GeoServer for maptiles

Tags: geoserver, tiles, geowebcache

I read the documentation for GeoServer but I can't seem to find a way by means of which one can update GeoWebCache dynamically by removing/deleting old (dirty map tiles) and then replace those dirty tiles with new maptiles and also how to dynamically create new maptiles in place of maptiles which are already removed being dirty and update the GeoWebCache dynamically?

Comment: I believe it is supposed to update automatically (i.e. if the data is changed, the cache gets updated). You may need to seed if want to see it in your cache. What are you trying and what behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: GeoWebCache does not know for example if there has been done updates in the database. You should get the dirty bounding boxes by some external utility and reseed affected areas with REST reseed requests.

Comment: I have read in the documentation that Seeding is the process where map tiles are generated and cached internally from GeoWebCache. So does that mean one has to do it through RESTFUL services and there is no automatic way/tool/mechanism to reseed GeoWebCache